# Parameter list in c # web services in php

Tags: c#, php, web-services, list

I'm having trouble passing a parameter list in php in a web service c #.

The Web services in c# is as follows:

```
[WebMethod ()]
public string IncluirOrcamento (List <ProdutosOrcamento> Products)
{
...
}
```

Where ProdutosOrcamento is a class in c# represented in this way ..

```
public class ProdutosOrcamento
{
         public string ProductCode {get; sets;}
         public Nullable <double> quantity {get; sets;}
}
```

Done this way in php ...

```
<? php
require_once ('/ lib / nusoap.php');

$ array = array ("Product" => array ("ProdutosOrcamento" => array (
'ProductCode' => '44 ',
'quantity' => '2 ')
"ProdutosOrcamento" => array (
'ProductCode' => '55 '​​,
'quantity' => '13 ')));

/ / print_r ($ array);
$ wsdl = "http://localhost:33328/KasviService.asmx?WSDL";
$ function = "IncluirOrcamento";
$ client = new nusoap_client ("http://localhost:33328/KasviService.asmx?WSDL", array ('location' => 'http://localhost:33328/KasviService.asmx?WSDL'));

$ result = $ client-> call ("IncluirOrcamento", $ array);

if ($ client-> fault) {
print_r ($ result);
else {}
     $ err = $ client-> getError ();
if ($ err) {
echo 'Error <h2> </ h2> <pre>'. $ err. '</ pre>';
     else {}
print_r ($ result);
     }
}
?>
```

I pass an array of objects, but my problem is that only considered the last object in the array, and I can not build a list with lots of objects. Does anyone know how to pass a list of objects in php web services for C #?

Comment: You have something wrong with the names of variables. You shouldnt slit `$` and varname.

Comment: the first 2 snippets are in C #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'll assume the extra spaces you have in your code & data is just copy/paste formatting problems because, as written, your code generates a fatal error.

Assuming that the extra spaces are the only copy/paste issue, the problem is that you're overwriting your array data by re-using the same key:

```
$array = array(
    "Product" => array(
        "ProdutosOrcamento" => array( // key:  ProdutosOrcamento
            'ProductCode' => '44 ',
            'quantity' => '2 ')  // You're also missing a comma here...
        "ProdutosOrcamento" => array( // key:  ProdutosOrcamento again!
            'ProductCode' => '55 '​​,
            'quantity' => '13 ')
    )
);
```

So the array representing ProductCode 55 is overwriting the array representing ProductCode 44.

Comment: Really Bill, the spaces were problems copy paste ..
how do I use different keys and my C # code can understand how object "ProdutosOrcamento"?